# Ajax Success function only works once

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't really understand jQuery all that well, but I've gone through some similar questions and haven't figured this out yet. Upon success of the ajax call I'd like a second jQuery function to fire. I feel like I'm getting close, the second function will work on the first Ajax call but not after that. The Ajax works every time without issue, but the success function does not. Am I missing something simple here?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.room').click(function() {

        var roomID = $(this).attr('id');
        var action = 'getDevices';
        var url = 'pages/connectedDevices.php';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            data: {
                action: action,
                roomID: roomID
            },

            success: typeResult
        });

        function typeResult(data) {
            $(".infoPaneData").empty().typed({
                strings: [(data)],
                typeSpeed: 2,
                backDelay: 500,
                loop: false,
                contentType: 'html', // or text
                // defaults to false for infinite loop
                loopCount: false
            });

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Insert a `console.log("Hey, I am working!")` as first line into your `typeResult` function to see whether it gets called or not … (and then look into your browser’s console, if not obvious.)

Comment: I inserted that, and it counts up every time I click on the "room" button. But I am not getting the data result.

Comment: Maybe that `typed` function you are using doesn’t work when it is called repeatedly on the same element or something?

Comment: Yeah I think you may be right, I am trying to use typed.js, but found a css solution that I'll try to implement instead. Thanks